# Script only works properly on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that makes a side panel `(.link-panel)` stop when it reaches `(.footer)`, inside `(.link-panel)` is `(.cover)`. `(.cover)` is the div that contains all the elements of the `(.link-panel`) so it is fixed and technically it is the one that stops when it reaches the `(.footer)`. My function first initializes if `.control_panel` is at `position: inline-block`. If it isn't (meaning it's `display: block` and the page width is <= 750px), then an else statement initializes and makes `.cover`'s position relative.

This function is working properly only on page refresh. For example, let's say my page's size is at: 1300px. The display works correctly, but when I shrink the window size to below <= 750px, the side-menu stays fixed even if I change the css property using jQuery. The problem can only be solved if I refresh the page. Then if I start at <= 750px and resize back up, the side menu does not display correctly and I have to refresh the page again for it to display correctly.

**My code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var panel = $(".control_panel").css("display");
    if(panel == "inline-block"){
        fixedScrollBar();

    }else{
         $(".link-panel").css("position", "relative");
    }

});




function fixedScrollBar(){
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw),
        $bumper = $(elem),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top + -40,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 60
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {

        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

        $('.cover').followTo('.footer');

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in a resize event, test in your scroll event if the panel is inline-block and disable the css  functions if its not:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var panel = $(".control_panel").css("display");
    if (panel == "inline-block") {
      fixedScrollBar();

    } else {
      $(".cover").css({"position":"relative","top":0});
    }
  }).trigger('resize');
});


function fixedScrollBar() {
  var windw = this;
  $.fn.followTo = function(elem) {
    var $this = this,
      $window = $(windw),
      $bumper = $(elem),
      bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top + -40,
      thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
      setPosition = function() {
         if($(".control_panel").css("display") == "inline-block") {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
          $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
          });
        } else {
          $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 60
          });
        }
      };
  }
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
  };

  $('.cover').followTo('.footer');

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e9dcmL2q/4/

Comment: Wrap everything from $(document).ready(function() to the end of the fixedScrollBar function?

Comment: yes, all except document ready & any function body, i can see another resize event in your page, what purpose does it have?

Comment: I obtained this function on Stack Overflow and modified it a bit. The resize function was their idea, but I removed it now since it serves no purpose really. Also, I tried to wrap my code in the resize event function that you said to do, but it still does not work correctly. It only works upon page refresh

Comment: @user2896120 can you provide a working example of your code?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the function does not initialize at all for some reason, and the side bar overlaps with the footer

Comment: Yes, let me make a jsFiddle of what i'm experiencing

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9dcmL2q/ Notice how the script does not work with the resize function in place

Comment: Resize the window back up to > 750px and then run the code. You'll see that when you resize back down, the menu is still at fixed position and will only display correctly if you hit run/refresh